# can you put variables in with writing? See for details

Tags: java

Is there a way to simplify this code by maybe putting like writing and then a variable and then writing again? I mean all on one line.

```
class tests {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int david, mark, alex;
    david = 20;
    mark = 30;
    alex = 12;

        System.out.println("hey");
    System.out.print("I can't believe that mark is ");
    System.out.print(mark);
    System.out.print(" years old.. thank god alex and david are  ");
    System.out.print(alex);
    System.out.print(" and ");
    System.out.print(david);
    System.out.print("...");
 }

}
```

Notice how many System.out.print's it took just to write something that simple? Is there anyway to simplify this well still using those variables?

Comment: you could use c style printf, System.out.printf();

Comment: And the answers keep flooding in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("hey");
sb.append("\n");
sb.append("I can't believe that mark is ");
sb.append(mark);
sb.append(" years old.. thank god alex and david are  ");
sb.appendt(alex);
sb.append(" and ");
sb.append(david);
sb.append("...");
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

if you doing like below code will give you little performance issue.

```
System.out.println("hey\n I can't believe that mark is "+mark+" years old.. thank god alex and david are  "+alex+" and "+david+"...");
```

Each '+' operation it will create new String object.

Use  [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)  for String concatenation operations. You can append more string to StringBuilder as you need. if you want clear the StringBuilder use myStringBuilder.setLength(0); or create new StringBuilder object.

Comment: He said he wanted it all on one line

Comment: But here we are just replacing "System.out.println" with "sb.append() ".. Its making no difference whatsoever...

Comment: `Is there a way to simplify this code by maybe putting like writing and then a variable and then writing again? **I mean all on one line.**`. He wanted **ALL** the code on one line

Comment: What is the point of that? ;o kind of confused can you explain the StringBuilder use a bit more indepth?

Comment: `StringBuilder` takes strings and jams the together. At the beginning, the `StringBuilder` is empty. After you append `hey`, `StringBuilder` contains `hey`. After you append `\n`, `StringBuilder` contains `hey\n`. `sb.toString` turns the `StringBuilder` into a `String`

Comment: So could you do that, and then start a brand new stringbuilder? Hmmm Or is it not possible because it would be full? or does it empty when you use it here:        System.out.println(sb.toString());

Comment: What i am saying above is.. if i did this stringbuilder method, and I wanted to do the stringbuilder again for a new line of text would it be possible?

Comment: @user3107180 yes you can append more string as you need. if you want clear the StringBuilder use myStringBuilder.setLength(0); or create new StringBuilder object.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do it like this:

```
System.out.println("hey\n I can't believe that mark is "+mark+" years old.. thank god alex and david are  "+alex+" and "+david+"...");
```

**note:** since you are using `println`(which indicate new line) for *"hey"*, you need to add `\n` there

Comment: You need a `\n` between `hey` and `I can't`.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.printf("hey%n I can't believe that mark is %s years old.. thank god alex and david are  %s and %s...",mark,alex,david);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **String.format** method in this scenario.

```
int x = 10;
String name = "User1";

String result = String.format("Hi %s, this is your number %d",name,x);
System.out.println(result);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("hey\n").append("I can't believe that mark is ").append(mark).append(" years old.. thank god alex and david are  ").append(alex).append(" and ").append(david).append("...");

System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

You really don't want to use "+" to concatenation a lot of strings for performance reasons.